# iPhone/Android Nearby Filesharing Systems Across Platforms

Tags: bluetooth, ios, file-sharing

In the past, I have been excluded from group chats, denied entry into groups and overall discriminated against because I have an Android while almost everyone I know has an iPhone. I have been trying to find ways to integrate iPhone and Android functionalities, to bring the two platforms closer together. I had found the app "WeMessage" that would allow an Android user to use iMessage, but I haven't set it up yet. Next, I wondered if there was a way to send and receive using the iPhone's AirDrop functionality on an Android. My phone, a Huawei Mate SE, has a function called Huawei Share, but it only works with other Huawei phones. So does anyone know how AirDrop works or how one could use a nearby filesharing system across platforms?

Comment: I think you can get your answer by this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202398/android-to-ios-airdrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible as AirDrop uses Bluetooth to create a peer-to-peer Wi-Fi network between the devices.
But here are some ways Android and iPhone/iOS users can share files with each other:

```
1.Use email
2. Use an app to share locally Like Zapya or Shareit
3. Use an app to share semi-locally
4. Use an online file-transfer service
```

Or you can jailbreak you i-device then use your Bluetooth connection to share data between i-devices and  others.